# Type script error TS1005: ',' expected while npm run build

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, build

My Typescript version is 4.1.2
and ts-node-dev version : 1.0.0

When i am trying to compile, via npm run build, i am getting below errors :

```
> @ build /root/imanagedsnodetracking
> rimraf dist && tsc --build

node_modules/cheerio-select/lib/index.d.ts:1:15 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1 import { type Options as CSSSelectOptions } from "css-select";
                ~~~~~~~

node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/index.d.ts:2:23 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

2 export { Parser, type ParserOptions };
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/index.d.ts:4:27 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

4 export { DomHandler, type DomHandlerOptions };
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/index.d.ts:32:37 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32 export { default as Tokenizer, type Callbacks as TokenizerCallbacks, } from "./Tokenizer.js";
```

I tried to change the javascript versions, but ending up in same errors.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import type { Options as CSSSelectOptions }`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.